# Setting minimum padding between linegraph and x axis in android achart

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I have developed an android app that uses the Achartengine graphing library. Everything is working ok, but the min value of y axis touches the x axis. How do I set a minimum distance between the minimum y point in the line graph and the x axis.

Here is an image:

[image]

The graph touches the x axis even though the value is not zero (its 26.3). I want to have a minimum space between the minimum y axis point value and the x axis for readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
renderer.setXLabelsPadding(10);
renderer.setYLabelsPadding(10);
```

Is this useful to you?

Comment: No it doesn't help at all

Answer (score 0):

You can change the axes minimum visible values this way:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(minValueX);
renderer.setYAxisMin(minValueY);
```

where `minValueX` is the minimum value on the X axis minus a small amount, `25` could be a good value in your case. Similar for the Y axis.